# Creating new div onmousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i would like to create new div onmousedown and i would like to resize it on mouse move. But i can't seem to get the mistake i've made.

```js
var x1;
var y1;
var pressed = false;
document.getElementById("primary").onmousedown = function() {
  pressed = true;
  var ok = true;

  if (ok === true) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    x1 = Math.round(event.clientX);
    y1 = Math.round(event.clientY);
    div.style.left = x1 + "px";
    div.style.top = y1 + "px";
    div.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
};
document.getElementById("primary").onmousemove = function() {
  if (pressed) {
    var div = get.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier");
    var x2 = Math.round(event.clientX) + x1;
    var y2 = Math.round(event.clientY) + y1;
    div.style.width = x2 + "px";
    div.style.height = y2 + "px";
  }

}
document.getElementById("primary").onmouseup = function() {
  pressed = false;
}
```

```css
#primary {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you testing `ok` immediately after you assign it? It will always be the value you just assigned.

Comment: `get.getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo. `get.getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`. When I fix that, the code works.

```js
var x1;
var y1;
var pressed = false;
document.getElementById("primary").onmousedown = function() {
  pressed = true;
  var ok = true;

  if (ok === true) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    x1 = Math.round(event.clientX);
    y1 = Math.round(event.clientY);
    div.style.left = x1 + "px";
    div.style.top = y1 + "px";
    div.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
};
document.getElementById("primary").onmousemove = function() {
  if (pressed) {
    var div = document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier");
    var x2 = Math.round(event.clientX) + x1;
    var y2 = Math.round(event.clientY) + y1;
    div.style.width = x2 + "px";
    div.style.height = y2 + "px";
  }

}
document.getElementById("primary").onmouseup = function() {
  pressed = false;
}
```

```css
#primary {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary"></div>
```

Comment: i'm new to JS is it possible to target any element not just with speciffic id or class ?

Comment: Yes. If you have a variable containing the element, you can add an event listener to it. For instance, you can do `div.onclick = function()...`

Comment: i mean all of them at once

Comment: You can put it on `body` so it will fire when you click anywhere.

Comment: you probably also have to disable pointerevents for the div you are moving with the mouse.